# For a certain 8 bit image imagecolorallocate() returns false for most colors

Tags: php, gd

I need the "color identifier" for text color which I need to pasted on an image using imagettftext(). I have found that for certain images imagecolorallocate can return false. But nowhere is indicated why this is or which colors will cause this. 8 bit is a good indicator but I can't change to a higher bit value.

Trough trial and error I found a number that works and gives a color I was looking for (between 0 - 255). That isn't really a workable solution because whenever I change the image I will again have to go look for a number that works.

```
$main_text_font_color = imagecolorallocate($certificate,
        $font_color['red'],
        $font_color['green'],
        $font_color['blue']
);
imagettftext($certificate, $text_size, 0, $text_h, $text_start, $main_text_font_color, $font_url, $text);
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to predict which colors will cause a false and which colors will work.

**Update:**
So I didn't find an answer to the question but thanks to @misorude I payed attention to the first comment on the [imagecolloralocate  documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php#94785) and am using a workaround mentioned in the comment. [`imagecolorclosest()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorclosest.php) gives a really good approximation of the color I was looking for. jahservant13's comment also gives some nice background information on `imagecolloralocate` not mentioned in the documentation.

As the color being perfect was not a requirement, this in essence is the answer I was looking for. I'm not posting this as the answer because it is not *actually* the answer to the question and I am still interested in knowing if there is an actual answer.

Comment: It could for example be due to what the first user comment in the manual mentions, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php#94785

Comment: @misorude The strange thing is the function always worked without trouble, when we changed the image from a 24 bit to an 8 bit image `imagecolloralocate()` started returning false.